# How to add my custom layout in top of notifications in status bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications

I need to add a RelativeLayout with a TextView and a Button in it to top of notifications in status bar.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @android_beginner Tried! But nothing useful! help me if you've found something!

Comment: Go with the first link given by @Froll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your XML Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="3dp"
              >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
              />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#000"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Your Code**

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.notification_image);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "Hello, this message is in a custom expanded view");
notification.contentView = contentView;


Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
```

**Sending Notification**

```
mNotificationManager.notify(CUSTOM_VIEW_ID, notification);
```

Reference :- ftp://ftp.gunadarma.ac.id/android/sdk/sdk_310712/docs/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html